# Error when deriving Copy on a struct containing nalgebra's VectorN type

Tags: types, rust

I'm attempting to use [nalgebra's `VectorN`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/base/type.VectorN.html) type to implement some dimension-agnostic calculations, but I'm getting some odd errors around the `Copy` trait. The below contrived test case demonstrates the problem:

```
extern crate nalgebra;

use nalgebra::allocator::Allocator;
use nalgebra::{DefaultAllocator, DimName, Real, VectorN};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub struct LinearPathSegment<N: Real, D: DimName>
where
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<N, D>,
{
    pub some_vec: VectorN<N, D>,
    pub some_scalar: N,
}
```

[Clone and run `cargo build` in this repo to reproduce](https://github.com/jamwaffles/so-vector-copy-demonstration/commit/19de33dd22b57e2c2ec297f101b93935a4675b25)

The error output by the compiler (rustc 1.29.1 (b801ae664 2018-09-20)) is this:

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
  --> src/lib.rs:6:24
   |
6  | #[derive(Clone, Debug, Copy, PartialEq)]
   |                        ^^^^
...
11 |     pub some_vec: VectorN<N, D>,
   |     --------------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
```

I'm certain that `VectorN` does implement `Copy`; by following the type aliases through the chain `VectorN<...> -> MatrixMN<...> -> Matrix<...>` we see that [`Copy` is `#[derive()]`d on `Matrix`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/src/nalgebra/base/matrix.rs.html#75), which should mean it is derived for `VectorN` too. Why is the compiler saying otherwise? What do I need to do to make `VectorN` copyable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add the bound `Owned<N, D>: Copy`. [`Owned`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/base/storage/type.Owned.html) is used as part of the [`MatrixMN`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/base/type.MatrixMN.html) type alias. `Owned` ends up being a type alias for [`MatrixArray`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/base/struct.MatrixArray.html).

```
extern crate nalgebra;

use nalgebra::{DefaultAllocator, DimName, Real, VectorN};
use nalgebra::allocator::Allocator;
use nalgebra::storage::Owned;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub struct LinearPathSegment<N: Real, D: DimName>
where
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<N, D>,
    Owned<N, D>: Copy,
{
    pub some_vec: VectorN<N, D>,
    pub some_scalar: N,
}
```

[`Real`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/trait.Real.html) requires `Copy`, and [`DimName`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/base/dimension/trait.DimName.html) requires [`Dim`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/nalgebra/base/dimension/trait.Dim.html) which requires `Copy`, so `N` and `D` don't need to have an explicit `Copy` bound. But for some reason, the compiler is unable to prove that `MatrixArray` is `Copy`. I suspect this comes from the bound `GenericArray<N, Prod<R::Value, C::Value>>: Copy` in its `Copy` implementation.

Another option is to add the bound `VectorN<N, D>: Copy`.

Note that either option forces every use of your struct to meet that bound. If that's not what you want, you must write a manual impl for `Copy` with the appropriate bounds instead of deriving it.

```
impl<N, D> Copy for LinearPathSegment<N, D>
where
    N: Real,
    D: DimName,
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<N, D>,
    VectorN<N, D>: Copy,
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deriving `Copy` is special in this case, because `Matrix` is generic:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Hash, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Matrix<N: Scalar, R: Dim, C: Dim, S> {
    /// The data storage that contains all the matrix components and informations about its number
    /// of rows and column (if needed).
    pub data: S,

    _phantoms: PhantomData<(N, R, C)>,
}
```

The marker `Copy` is implemented only if `N`, `R`, `C` and `S` are also `Copy`.

Indeed, you can see this line in the `Matrix` documentation page:

```
impl<N: Copy + Scalar, R: Copy + Dim, C: Copy + Dim, S: Copy> Copy for Matrix<N, R, C, S>
```

As a simpler example, this code compiles fine:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct DummyWrapper<T>(T);

fn main() {
}
```

But of course, you can copy `DummyWrapper` only if `T` is copyable too:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct DummyWrapper<T>(T);

fn consume<T>(_t: T) {}

fn main() {
    // Ok
    let a = DummyWrapper(42);
    consume(a);
    consume(a);

    // Error: move occurs because `a` has type `DummyWrapper<std::string::String>`,
    // which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    let a = DummyWrapper(String::from("test"));
    consume(a);
    consume(a);
}
```

---

To make your struct copyable, I am only guessing, but you should add the following bounds:

```
N: Copy, D: Copy
```

Comment: Hmm, `Real` [requires `Copy`](https://docs.rs/alga/0.7.2/src/alga/general/real.rs.html#33) so that's already correctly bounded. [`DimName`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.16.4/src/nalgebra/base/dimension.rs.html#193-206) doesn't, but adding copy with `D: DimName + Copy` just gives me the same error. There's also the issue that I'm trying to use `VectorN<N, D>` which doesn't let me add bounds on `R`, `C` or `S` as they're hidden by the alias. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Bojangles Do not use the alias, use `Matrix<N, D, U1, Owned<N, D, U1>>`?

Comment: Gave that a go too, still no dice. This is really confusing!